# How to map routes http://localhost:53244/page.aspx?ID=7842 to http://localhost:53244/Home

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes

Need to mapped route e.g http://localhost:53244/page.aspx?ID=7842 to http://localhost:53244/Home and need to pass default query string in new maped URL

i have already tried `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "Home", "~/Page.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "ID", "7844" } });`
but its not working for me because i need id in request.querystring not in `Page.RouteData.Values["ID"]`

This is my basic code `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "Home/{*queryvalues}", "~/Page.aspx", false);`
in which i can use url like http://localhost:53244/Home?ID=7842 but i need only http://localhost:53244/Home

Answer (score 1):

Using Web.Config you can use URL mapping

```
 <system.web> 
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
      <add
          url="~/page.aspx?ID=.."
          mappedUrl="~/Home" />  
  </system.web>
```

For more info check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976111/introduction-to-url-rewriting-to-url-mapping-and-to-url-routing-in-asp)

To handle all pages that the page.aspx return you can use url rewriting rules

```
<rewriteModule>
  <rewriteOn>true</rewriteOn>
  <rewriteRules>
      <rule source="(.*)/Home"  
         destination="page.aspx?ID=$1"/> 
  </rewriteRules>
</rewriteModule>
```